# JavaScript: Data stream compression/decompression

Tags: javascript, stream, gzip, compression

I am trying to make a peer-to-peer file storage system, and I can either make a Java client program for desktop computers and an Android application, or just make a JavaScript and HTML client on a web page. I think it's easier to make a web page, since everybody can use it.

But I have a problem: The file servers send compressed data. They use "Deflate" (which I think is gZip, but I'm not sure). Is there any way to decompress a stream of data in client-sided JavaScript? I'm not talking about Node.js. And can you also compress a stream of data with gZip, in JavaScript?
I know I'm pushing what a scripting language is intended for, but it'll take less time for me to make a web page than a Java client program.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there anyway to decompress a stream of data in client-sided JavaScript?"

On browsers other than Firefox and IE, now there is! Enter the Compression Stream API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompressionStream

Gzip and Deflate are supported.

You will also need to use `ReadableStream` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream).

Simple example from MDN:

```
const compressedReadableStream = inputReadableStream.pipeThrough(
  new CompressionStream("gzip")
);
```

Comment: Unless you want to saddle the world with another "Works only in Chrome" website, wait for Safari & Firefox to implement it too (they haven't as of 20 March 2023).  But the bright side is you can already use this in Node applications.

Comment: By the way, it's supported by Mozilla Firefox since its version 113 released in May 2023.